# mysqlにtsvファイルをインポートしたい

Tags: mysql

現在作成しているテーブルのレコードとしてtsvファイルになっているデータをインサートしたいと思っています。一つ一つ手打ちで入れていくのは果てしなく時間がかかってしまいます。
tsvファイルには作成テーブルのフィールド数と同じデータ数が入っています。

つまり、tsvファイルをインポートしたら指定したテーブルに挿入され完成してしまうといった形にしたいのですが可能でしょうか。

ご教授お願いします。また足りない情報があればご指摘ください。

Comment: tsvをmysqlにInsertするプログラムを作りたいのか、そういう操作をしたいのかどちらですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。操作をしたいと思っております。

Answer (score 1):

mysqlimport コマンドか、LOAD DATA クエリを使えばできると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。使ってみたのですが文法違いのエラーがでてしまいまして、どこがまちがっているかすらもわからない状態です。

Comment: tsvファイルのタブ（文字コード 0x09)をカンマ(,)に置換して、csvファイルを作ります。そのcsvファイルを読み込んでも文法違いのエラーが出るなら、データに問題があると判断できますので、原因の切り分けに役立つかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとございます。基本的にｃｓｖにしないといけないということですかね？

Comment: 違います。csvにする必要は一般にはありません。「文法違い」のエラーが出た原因が、tsv形式を使った事に因るのか、データ自体に因るのかを判断する手段として一旦tsv形式ではないデータで試してみてはどうかという提案をしただけです。　どんなエラーメッセージが出されたのか等、具体的な情報が質問に書かれていないので、原因の切り分けに有効と思われる手段を提案してみました。

Comment: なるほど。試してみます。初心者なもので見当違いの質問失礼いたしました。